# Looking for a jQuery solution to control container height in 20px increments rounding up to nearest 20px dimension

Tags: jquery, css

I have a design conundrum. The site specs I have in front of me (and support psd files) have a main body container with stitched edges. I also have dynamic content and know that the stitches will get clipped in odd places as the height adjusts to the content and this will look like crap.

What I would like ideally is to control and round up the container height in a predictable way so that I know that the container will always be divisible by say 20px so that my background slice wont ever get clipped in between a stitch.

So in classic fashion I will have a top cap at a set height of 30px, a bottom cap the same and then a 20px slice that will repeat to fill the main content area. This content area height is what I need to always be divisible by 20.

```
<div id="container">
<div id="top_cap"></div>
<div id="content_area">
[CONTENT]
</div><!--END CONTENT AREA-->
<div id="bottom_cap"></div>
</div><!--END CONTAINER-->
```

Any ideas are most welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/b52qT/2/

Better demo by thirtyDot
http://jsfiddle.net/d4Q3S/

```
$(function(){
    var curHeight = parseInt($("#content_area").height()),
        newHeight = Math.ceil(curHeight/20) * 20;
    $("#content_area").height(newHeight );
});
```

Comment: Looks good. I would just add that `.height()` will always return the content height, regardless of the value of the CSS box-sizing property, per jQuery. So I think the OP would have to add borders and padding when calculating the `curHeight`

Comment: I was in the process of writing the "same answer". I've got a [nice demo going](http://jsfiddle.net/d4Q3S/), but I won't bother to post it as an answer now.

Comment: yeah, i like this method better than mine.  +1

Comment: Those are great. That demo is really perfect for demonstration! Thanks guys! I will have to post a link to the live version. A quick test based on thirtydot's solution is super duper promising.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery to take the height mod 20, like so:

```
var difference = 20 - ($("#content_area").height() % 20);
```

Then, add that to the height of your content area:

```
$("#content_area").height( $("#content_area").height() + difference);
```

You could combine those two statements easily. However, as a disclaimer ensure that height is not including your borders, etc, as you may want to subtract those from the `.height()` when calculating the difference.

Comment: i don't know that adding the difference works every time.  for instance, with the height of 205, the mod would return 5, which would result in the height being set to 210, which is not divisible by 20.

Comment: Oh - very true. You should instead subtract the difference from 20 and add that.

Comment: i would suggest either editing the answer to be more accurate or deleting it to avoid confusion.